# Extract data from a pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

This is a sample of the DataFrame that I have and I want to extract the corresponding data of "totalCount" according to each time frame.

```
df = [{"username": "last",
"time_data": "{\"hours\":[{\"hour\":\"00:00\",\"postCount\":\"5\",\"topicCount\":\"3\",\"totalCount\":80},{\"hour\":\"01:00\",\"postCount\":\"11\",\"topicCount\":\"6\",\"topciCount\":31}"
},
{"username": "truk",
 "time_data": "{\"hours\":[{\"hour\":\"00:00\",\"postCount\":\"11\",\"topicCount\":\"6\",\"totalCount\":362},{\"hour\":\"01:00\",\"postCount\":\"22\",\"topicCount\":\"8\",\"topicCount\":355}"
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

I have used this code to get the "postCount" of both '00:00' and '01:00':

```
df_h0 = df.copy()
df_h0['hour']='00:00'
df_h0['totalCount']=df.time_data.str.split('"00:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h0 = df_h0.fillna(0)

df_h1 = df.copy()
df_h1['hour']='01:00'
df_h1['totalCount']=df.time_data.str.split('"01:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h1 = df_h1.fillna(0)

df_tot = df_h0.append([df_h1])
df_tot.head()
```

But now I want to get the "totalCount" which is not just next to the hours. Anyone knows how to do that?

Expected output:

```
                           time_data                 username   hour    totalCount
0   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"5","top...   last    00:00   80
1   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"11","to...   truk    00:00   362
0   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"5","top...   last    01:00   31
1   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"11","to...   truk    01:00   355
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem as it stands you should make a regular expression to extract the text at the correct position. But this is not the correct way to approach your problem. Ideally, to make the most of the DataFrame structure, you should parse the data when it is received into DataFrame colums so that you could use something more convenient and efficient:

```
totals_over_one_hundred = df.loc[df['totalCount'] > 100]
```

Comment: why are you assuming that all numbers in totalCount are >100?

Comment: I'm not, just giving an example of the types of statements you can make when you parse data into columns instead of just strings with all the info in one column. If I understand correctly your code currently just has the time_data as one column. Think of it as an Excel spreadsheet. You don't enter multiple data points in the same column because then you can't perform any operations on your data! pandas DataFrame is the same. You should parse your giant time_data strings into new columns of their own.